# How to keep cursor at chosen pos when value is changing?

Tags: vue.js, quasar

Hello my full question is "how to keep cursor at the chosen position while :model.value change on different circumstances?
code example:

```
<q-input 
 :modelValue="article" 
 ref="editor"
/>
```

script:

```
const article = ref( 'is a very popular animal')

function writeCrocodyle() {
 setInterval(()=>{
  doc_text.insert(0, 'Crocodyle')
 },1000)
}
writeCrocodyle()

/* Pretend this function is called each time when some differences in text show up
 to be more specific in my app is managed by websocket an yjs lib for this question absolute negligible */ 
function update() {
article.value = doc_text.toString()
editor.value?.getNativeElement().setSelectionRange(pos.value.index, pos.value.index)
}
```

it works this way

```
function update() {
 article.value = doc_text.toString()
 setTimeout(()=>{
  editor.value?.getNativeElement().setSelectionRange(pos.value.index, pos.value.index)
 }, 100)
}
```

but then i have un wanted delay. im looking for something like onAfterModelChangeRerender or orher solution please help.